# Pop art effect in iphone

Tags: iphone

Thanks in advance.

I want to get a pop art effect on a image (pop art effect means in photoshop we will get 4 photos with different effects of same photo) in iphone using objective c. Actually i dodn't know is it possible or not , if possible how to proceed. If any one know please help me.

Comment: At least, he accepted some...

Comment: Did you manage to get it done somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible with, for example, Apple's [CoreImage](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreGraphics/Reference/CoreGraphics_Framework/_index.html) framework, the algorithm should be easy to write, but harded to adjust:

**Pseudocode**:

```
image = loadImageFromFile("your image file");
popArt = createImage(/*width:*/ image.width * 2, 
                     /*height:*/ image.height * 2);

subdivisions = [ [ 0, image.width, 0, image.height ],
                 [ image.width, image.width, 0, image.height ],
                 [ 0, image.width, image.height, image.height ],
                 [ image.width, image.width,  image.height, image.height ] ];

blendFunctions = [ boost_red, boost_blue, boost_yellow, boost_green ];

for(i=0;i<4;++i) {
   fillRectangle(rectangle[i], /*dest. image:*/popArt, 
                            /*source image:*/image,
                            blendFunctions[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But i am not getting how to implement it. Will u give more clarification about it .